# ¿Cómo controlar el rango de un textbox (html.helper)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Necesito delimitar el input de un usuario entre `0.1~9999`. El control se está pintando con `@html.TextBox` sin usar `dataanotations` con alguna función Js, Jquery o atributo de HTML5.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

Con este código puedes resolver el problemas:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Cantidad, new { type="number", min="0.1", 
max="9999",  step="0.1"})
```

La parte `new { type="number", min="0.1", max="9999",  step="0.1"}` es para enviarle un diccionario con los parametros html.

Asi, el `helper Html`.`TextBox` sabra que ponerle al momento de dibujarlo.

> Nota: Para agregar una clase, debes usar `@class='MiClase'`

Esto te dara un resultado del siguente código:

```
<input name='Cantidad' id='Cantidad' type='number' 
min='0.1' max='999' step='0.1'>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Podrías agregar una explicación en que consiste ese código?

Comment: Por favor brinda más detalles sobre este código. Recuerda que a futuro habrán usuarios menos experimentados deseosos de aprender que pueden revisar esta publicación.

Comment: lo que hace ese código es agregar los atributos HTML

Answer (score 0):

Si lo quieres hacer con HTML5 tienes los [atributos min y max](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp) en el input, aunque pienso que lo mejor seria hacer código con javascript y luego volver a comprobar en el servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas es un `<input type='number'>`, como p. ej.:

```html
<input type='number' min='0.1' max='9999' step='0.1'>
```

Mira un [ejemplo](http://jsbin.com/tipucaqifi/edit?html,output), y consulta la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

Comment: Al utilizar type=number el control se pinta con un selector de valores no en un textbox

Comment: En realidad depende del navegador. En la mayoría de los casos un `<input type='number'>` sigue siendo un campo de texto, pero en el que sólo se pueden escribir números. Lo cual, para la mayoría de los casos de uso, es una buena idea.